# Como fazer uma consulta mysql a partir de um link

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, select, link, mysqli

Tenho visto em alguns sites links que fazem buscas mysql e retornam resultados, ou seja, fazer uma consulta mysql a partir de um link ao invés de um campo.

Supondo que o link dentro da tag *a* fosse assim:

```
href="https://www.meulink.com" name="camisas" >Camisas
```

O usuário clica no link, a consulta é feita no banco de dados retornando os valores correspondentes:

```
$sql = "SELECT roupas FROM estoque WHERE roupas='camisas';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["roupas"]."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nada foi encontrado.";
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em portugues, o que você já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode conseguir isso passando um parâmetro para a página, em seguida, o `PHP` pode pegar esse parâmetro e gerar o conteúdo, apropriado, para o leitor.
Por exemplo, ao clicar em camisas, você pode ter:

```
<a href="https://www.meulink.com" name="camisas" >Camisas</a>
```

Ação BackEnd:

```
if(isset($_POST['camisas'])){
//Se a pagina enviar como post um clique nas camisas, então execute mysql query
$sql = "SELECT roupas FROM estoque WHERE roupas='camisas';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["roupas"]."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nada foi encontrado.";
}
}
```

Lógico que existem várias formas de fazer o que você esta pedindo, este é um exemplo de como poderia funcionar para você, teste ai e veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: Paulo, mas como ficaria o parâmetro passado para a página?

Comment: @valpmg ja esta no código de exemplo, o parâmetro é justamente o "camisas", ele pegara o click no link que por sua vez enviara ao servidor um post com o clique e os dados e retornara a consulta, na mesma pagina ou em outra de acordo com o comportamento esperado da estrutura do seu site.

Comment: Não funcionou aqui. o link deve ficar dentro de um form post?

Comment: @valpmg Nesta situação deve-se usar `$_GET`. E ainda colocar no link `href="seulink.php?camisas".` Assim ele ira chamar o `if(isset($_GET['camisas']))`. Agora se quiser passa por `$_POST`. Ai deverá usar javascript.

Comment: Willian era exatamente isso que eu estava em dúdida. Valeu abraço